# ht access not work when parsing 2 paramete

Tags: .htaccess

Why my .htacces not working properly when I parse 2 parameter, my code:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/token/(.+)$ search.php?q=$1&pageToken=$2 [NC]
```

when I try in web with : `http://localhost:8080/yt/search/test/token/CBQQAA/`

the expected result: `search = test and token = CBQQAA`,

the real : `search = test/token/CBQQAA token =''`

This error becase I join 2 code, first with 1 parameter and second I use 2 parameter..How to do this combination? I want running with 1 parameter but sometimes I need 2 parameter if it have paging to another page
please help me to solve it..thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.+` is greedy in your regex. Use `[^/]+` to get precise matching:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/token/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&pageToken=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Better to turn off `MultiViews` as your URL start `search` is matching php file name `search.php`.

Comment: sory I think your code solve it...but the new problem...I want running it with 1 parameter and sometimes 2 parameter...how  do this combination...I think becase I join this code it become error

RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/$ search.php?q=$1

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/token/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&pageToken=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

Comment: I have been update the question, please help me if you know how to use both of them? thank in advance

Comment: I had already updated the answer after your comment and that should still work.